# Chrome span rendering problem

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a running news ticker, displaying correctly in FF but not all version of chrome:

```
<div id="a" style="position:fixed; bottom:50px; height:30px;">
  <span id="b" style="display:inline; position:absolute;">blah blah text one two three.</span>
</div>
```

when document is loaded, I call jquery function to set css, (set the LEFT of #b to move from right to left) while the text is completed off the screen, I reset the LEFT of #b to screen.width.

but the text of #b will be cut out to only 1-2 word, (FF shows correctly like a news ticker) under some investigation, I found out under chrome the text got broken into multi-lines and never change back.

I was wondering how can I avoid this? or this is chrome's bug

Answer (score 0):

I have checked this on Opera and text is also broken into multi-lines. So probably this isn't only Chrome issue. I have fixed multi-line problem by removing `position: absolute`. Is this position required for animation?

EDIT: After checking this once again it is not a position issue. This issue appear because `a` doesn't have width and browser is trying to minimize width of `b` to minimum. If you add width attribute this should fix a problem. The best will work something more than 100% so there is a place on right for hidden `b`. Here is and example of this solution with width 200% - it works on Opera, FF and Chrome.

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="javascript">
var pos = innerWidth;
function setTimer() {
    b = document.getElementById('b')
    pos = pos - 10;
    if(pos <= 0)
        pos = innerWidth;
    b.style.left = pos+"px";
    setTimeout(setTimer,100);
}

</script>
<button onclick="setTimer()">start</button>
<div id="a" style="position:fixed; bottom:50px; height:30px; background-color: gold; width:200%">
  <span id="b" style="position:absolute; background-color: teal">blah blah text one two three.</span>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I have removed position attribute, but still no luck.